# SQL Server: add total count to select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I am using the following stored procedure to fetch some basic data from a database which works fine so far.

Can someone tell me how I can add a total count here without creating an extra column ?
What I want is that in addition to fetching my data I just want to know how many records are returned which also needs to cover the case that there are no matching records.

**My stored procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CountQueue]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT      dateEsc,
                url,
                EID
    FROM        QueueLog
    WHERE       logStatus = 'New'
    AND         region = 'US'
    AND         (
                    flag = 'flag1' 
                    OR 
                    flag = 'flag2'
                )
    ORDER BY    dateEsc desc, EID desc
END
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use enviromental variable **@@ROWCOUNT**. It stores the number of rows affected by last executed statement.

Here is the reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. How would I include that in the above ?

Comment: Sorry for including non-english link before. I didn't notice that it wasn't english, though that google translate automatically tried to translate that.

Comment: As to the question: it depends what do you wish to do with it. Would you like to bind it to a variable and then save to a table? Log it? You can do eveything that you could do with standard variable declared in the procedure.